# Verify model assumptions with tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels

Outside of the tidymodels universe, it's easy to verify model assumptions.
For example with linear regression (function *lm*), the package *performance* create understandable graphics and easy functions (*check_heteroscedasticity()*) to verify assumptions of a linear regression model :

- normality of residuals
- independence of the residuals
- homogeneity of the residuals
- non-collinearity of the variables.

Is there in the tidymodels universe equivalent packages to verify assumptions of a model ? Tidymodels packages create parnsnip object, so old model evaluation packages like *performance* are useless.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I would say that the [`infer`](https://infer.netlify.app) is designed for that purpose; have a look at the [`hypothesise`](https://infer.netlify.app/reference/hypothesize.html) function.

Comment: Note that your terminology is not „correct“, i.e. you don‘t want to check your hypotheses, you want to check your model assumptions (!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fitted models you get from using {parsnip} or other {tidymodels} will contain the underlying fitted model for whatever engine you are using.

Sometimes the fitted parsnip object will work directly with the function you are using. This is the case with the `check_model()` function from {performance}.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(performance)

lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("lm")

lm_fit <- fit(lm_spec, mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)

lm_fit %>%
  check_model()
```

[image]

Other times you will get an error because the function doesn't know what to do with a `model_fit` object. You can use the `extract_fit_engine()` which will extract the fit produced by the engine, that can then be used with `check_heteroscedasticity()`.

```r
lm_fit %>% 
  extract_fit_engine() %>%
  check_heteroscedasticity()
#> OK: Error variance appears to be homoscedastic (p = 0.188).
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>